# Already have Android SDK installed, xamarin for visual studio 2017 is downloading it again

Tags: c#, android-studio, xamarin.android, download, visual-studio-2017

I already have installed android SDK latest version installed, but yesterday when I installed Visual Studio 2017 RC with xamarin mobile development component, it is again downloading android sdk. I want to install xamarin with visual studio, so that I can learn mobile mobile developement with other languages like c sharp. But I want everything installed in a simple way and with less data consumption. Is there any I can install xamarin with visual studio 2017, so I dont again have to download android sdk.

Comment: That's by design. As Xamarin requires the SDK to be installed to a specific location, while Google does not put a restriction on where you should install, it can end up with multiple SDK installed. Your wishes of "simple way" and "less data consumption" have conflicts, at least at this stage.

Comment: what if I change the location of previous sdk installation to that where xamarin needs?

Comment: When you installed the Android SDK, did you install it for one user or for all users of the machine?

Comment: For one user? I actually forgot.

Comment: That is the default option in the SDK installer, but in order to support multiple users on the same machine we install it globally. That could explain why we're downloading it again. (Disclosure: I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft)